# Form dropdown options not saving in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working with a form that belongs to the signup and account update pages with Devise. I've added 2 fields to the user model, Role and Gender.

I've setup my role field as:

```
<%= f.select :role, options_for_select([['Student - High School'], ['Student - Undergraduate'], ['Student - Nursing'], ['Student - Graduate'], ['Student - Medical'], ['Health Care - Resident'], ['Health Care - Nurse'], ['Health Care - Physician'], ['Health Care - Staff'], ['Other']]), class: 'form-control'  %>
```

and gender as:

```
<%= f.select :gender, options_for_select([['Male'], ['Female'], ['Other']]), class: 'form-control' %>
```

And in my application controller, I've asked Devise to permit:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [ :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :age, :name, role: [], gender:[]])
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [ :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :age, :name, role: [], gender: []])
end
```

Can you help me find the mistake I'm making?
Thank You!

Comment: Aren't role and gender single values after they are selected?  so :role and :gender

Comment: Do role and gender need to be arrays there? They look like normal strings so you could just use ```:role, :gender``` as usual.

Comment: @dbugger Yes, they would be one single value after selected.

Comment: @ellitt So how would I pre-define the selection for :role and :gender ? Do I just remove the array, and populate the options_for_select with strings separated by commas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the views:

`options_for_select(['Student - High School', 'Student - Undergraduate', 'Student - Nursing', 'Student - Graduate', 'Student - Medical', 'Health Care - Resident', 'Health Care - Nurse', 'Health Care - Physician', 'Health Care - Staff', 'Other'], selected: 'Student - High School')`

`options_for_select(['Male', 'Female', 'Other'], selected: 'Male')`

And this in the controller:

`devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [ :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :age, :name, :role, :gender ])`

`devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [ :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :age, :name, :role, :gender ])`

Comment: This works, but the selection stays static, not displaying the actual value in the dropdown. What can I do to show the actual value from the DB?

Comment: Remove the `selected:` from the `options_for_select`.

Comment: Now if we're talking about having it preselect a value for new users and show the DB value for existing users, then you might trying something like this: ```options_for_select(['Male', 'Female', 'Other'], selected: f.object.gender ? f.object.gender : 'Male')```

Comment: I removed selected: but it still shows the previous selected: value. I've restarted my server to try and clear any cache. Is there something else I should try?

Comment: What do you mean by previous selected value? The way rails form helpers work makes them populate the DB value by default if it exists.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, that I have this dropdown on the user edit page which displays the defaulted value of 'Male' for gender. I'd like it to display the current DB value on the edit page. I implemented the suggestion above, but it continues to default to the 'Male' option after change to 'Other' or 'Female'.

Comment: Can you confirm that whatever you change is being persisted to the DB? If you change the select to 'Other' and save, does that User.gender come back as 'Other'?

Comment: Yes, it persists to the DB, but not in the view

Comment: Ok without seeing what you've got now, I'm gonna guess and say try this: ```options_for_select(['Male', 'Female', 'Other'], selected: (f.object.gender || 'Male')```

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You should put your devise controllers into your app.

`rails generate devise:controllers [scope]`

Then put that permitted params method in the registrations controller

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_action : configure_permitted_parameters
  private
  #Your methods here
end
```

routes:
`devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}`